# JQuery UI datepicker Short Month

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im using the jqueryUI datepicker for the first time and i am displaying the calendar like so

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Now i am trying to display just a short month "Oct, Nov, etc" in the header but it's not working, any ideas what im missing.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker(
            {
                numberOfMonths: [3, 1],
                firstDay: 1,
                dateFormat: "d/mm/yy",
                monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
                                  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                    navigatedate(dateText, inst);


                }
            });
```

Comment: This worked  $("#datepicker").datepicker(
            {
                numberOfMonths: [3, 1],
                firstDay: 1,
                dateFormat: "d/mm/yy",
                monthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                    navigatedate(dateText, inst);


                }
            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944525/jquery-ui-datepicker-short-month#comment14282992_10944525)

> This worked

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [3, 1],
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: "d/mm/yy",
    monthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
                 "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        navigatedate(dateText, inst);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the alt format 'M' for the short month.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [3, 1],
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: "d/M/yy",
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        navigatedate(dateText, inst);
    }
});
```